# How do I separate elements horizontally in a flex container?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have my header in my html with three elements an image representing the logo, the title, and some icons, in that order. I already have them centered using flexbox but I want to keep the logo in the leftmost part of the screen and the icons on the opposite side, while keeping the title in the middle, this is my html:

```css
.title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.title .logo {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="title">
    <img class="logo" src="./img/logo.png" alt="" width="100" height="100">
    <h1 class="subtitle">Lorem ipsum dolor</h1>
    <div class="socials">
      <a href="">
        <i class="fab fa-facebook fa-2x"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

I have tried expanding the margin of the title, but it doesn't look good and here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgsxr.png) of what the header looks like:

Comment: use flex direction: row and justify content: space-between for you container

Comment: I hope this will help you!

Comment: @GulshanAggarwal - sounds like a working solution-- you should post as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [flexbox `auto`-margins](https://css-tricks.com/the-peculiar-magic-of-flexbox-and-auto-margins/) to achieve this effect:

```css
.title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.title .logo {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.logo {
  margin-right: auto;
}

.socials {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="title">
    <img class="logo" src="./img/logo.png" alt="" width="100" height="100">
    <h1 class="subtitle">Lorem ipsum dolor</h1>
    <div class="socials">
      <a href="">
        <i class="fab fa-facebook fa-2x"></i>
        fb
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></i>
        insta
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Just make a little change in your css file, Change justify-content to space-between for your title selector**

```css
.title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: I hope this helped you ! and for a bonus you can also  accept  my answer Thankyou!!